# EF6: How can we remove an unused navigation properties?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 6 in a database first model for a Microsoft SQL 2008 Server. On every table, there is an integer field called CreationUserID. This field is part of a foreign key to the table User where the primary key is UserId.

When the schema is generated from the database, a navigation property for the Creation User is created for every entity. Also, this make the User entity having a lot of navigation properties.

I would like to remove those navigation properties because we do not navigate by them. When I highlighted the relation between two tables, like User and Bank then I pressed delete key, the relation and the navigation property on both table got removed but I also got this message:

```
Error 3023: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 1494:
Column Bank.CreationUserId in table Bank must be mapped:
It has no default value and is not nullable.
```

I created a scalar integer property called CreationUserId on Bank entity and then I mapped the field CreationUserId to the property CreationUserId. I got this message:

```
Error 3007: Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines 1504, 1701:
Column(s) [CreationUserId] are being mapped in both fragments to different conceptual side properties.
```

What does this error means? Am I heading toward the wrong direction to achieve my goal?

Thank you!